# About owner and owned window in windows

Tags: c++, windows

How can i get all windows owned by a window? (not it's child)

Comment: What do you mean by 'owned' if you don't mean child?

Comment: Just break the window and hop in.  They usually keep them under the bed.

Comment: @sje397 - "owned windows" on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(v=VS.85).aspx#owned_windows

Comment: A window can have children that are not identified as 'child' windows, for instance java applet windows embedded in IE. The applet parent window is the page, but the applet window is a top level window and not marked as child.

Comment: Who on Earth are voting to close the question as "not real"? That voting is the tragedy of the commons, sure. Educational to see it action, yes. But.

Comment: @lovespring: check out `GetWindow` etc. I don't recall exactly but it may be that windows owned by a window W are right above it in Z-order. At least I don't think you can sort of snuggle any other window in between W and any of its owned windows. This requires some experimentation and/or googling so I leave the work to you. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use EnumWindows to get the list of windows and then, for each window handle, call GetWindow with GW_OWNER flag to get the owner. In this way you can get the list of owned windows for a specified window handle.

That's true. A parent window is not the same than the owner window.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)...

> An application can use the GetWindow
>   function with the GW_OWNER flag to
>   retrieve a handle to a window's owner.

The [documented API on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515%28VS.85%29.aspx). GetWindow used with the results from [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will give you the owned windows.

Comment: I don't wanna get the owner, i want all windows owned by a given window.

Comment: Sorry, skipped that step. Edited in... but it is almost the same as Jesus Oliva's answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you mean you will want to get the window's child windows, their child windows, etc.  To do that, you would need to call [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: My initial assumption is that, "(not its child)," would make this a pretty silly answer.  Part of me wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't though.

Comment: That will not return any top-level overlapped or popup windows owned by the current window.

Comment: Since he stated "All windows own by a window", I assume he meant "Not <b>just</b> its child in his question.  Getting overlapped and popup windows requires iterating through all windows and checking their owner ... which is probably not what he wanted (though I could be mistaken).

Comment: so, I have to iterating all top level window, to see if it is owned by a given window, is it?